What is the easiest method for forwarding ETW logs to Splunk receiver?
I am trying to forward some kernel-level events from my Splunk UF to my Splunk receiver.
I experienced with windows' built in utility - logman and was able to produce etl files and convert them to XML or JSON.
However I am struggling to understand how to actually send the logs.
I tried 2 add-ons:
https://github.com/vector-sec/TA_ETW
https://github.com/airbus-cert/Splunk-ETW
But still I was not able to actually send the events.
I am thinking about writing my own add-on but I do not want to spend a lots of time on this.
How difficult is it to use the logman C# API?
Are there any working solutions that I did not try?
Alternatively, did someone was able to use the add-ons I mentioned earlier and care to give their professional opinion?
Thank you.

Why are you "not able to actually send the events"?  What error messages do you get?  Did you follow the installation instructions for the cited add-ons?  Both specify inputs.conf settings that should send events to Splunk.  Do you see events from your UF in Splunk's _internal index?  If not, then the problem is with the UF configuration rather than anything to do with ETW.

I viewed the splunk.log file but I could find any log that was related to my issue from the 10 minutes subsequent to my restart. It contained mainly INFO level messages.
I did follow for the installation which concluded 2 steps:
splunk.exe install app .\Splunk-ETW.tar.gz
splunk.exe enable app Splunk-ETW
and editing inputs.conf like so:
[Splunk-ETW://cert]
The _internal does contain some logs with the addres of my UF machine.
It is worth mensioning that any none ETW log such as  Windows and Sysmon logs is forwarded properly.

Eventually I used SilkETW which worked very well and also support running the tracing as a service.
I configured it to write to the event log as an independent service and then used the event log mechanism to send it to my Splunk receiver as a regular log.
[WinEventLog://SilkService-Log]
disabled = 0
index = main
sourcetype = SilkService-Log:Logs

